# ExecutorService wait for all Future to complete

Tags: java, executorservice

I have below code for ExecutorService.

```
try{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    List<Callable<String>> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>(5);
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        taskList.add(new SimpleTask());
    }

    List<Future<String>> list =  executor.invokeAll(taskList);
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println(list.get(0).get());
    System.out.println("Exit");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

class SimpleTask implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {     
        return new Date().toString();
    }
}
```

I want to know `list.get(0).get()` will wait for all task to complete?

Comment: No it will wait for just one `Future` (the first one) to complete

Comment: As Wombat say, no. So, are you asking for ways to do that or does that answer your question?

Comment: I have put breakpoint in call() and skip for first Task. Then also waiting for all Task to complete.

Comment: If you put a break point in `call()`, you'll have to skip it five times because that's how often it will be called. That sounds like the reason it's waiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here code will not wait while execution of `list.get(0).get()` statement but `executor.invokeAll(taskList)` statement because `invokeAll()` method itself will wait for complication of all the threads.

To learn more [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798567/4392892)

Answer (score -1):

No, the code as it is will not wait for every task to finish. By calling `list.get(0).get()` you are retrieving the very first optional call `get()` on it which will block the thread according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--).

To wait for every callable to finish you need to iterate through the list and see if all are done. Of course you can do this by calling `get()` on every single one of them but then you would block your main thread the whole time. I myself prefer to being able to do stuff while i am waiting for other threads to execute.

**Example using Java 8 streams:**

```
// filter if any future is not done yet
while ( list.stream().anyMatch(i->!i.isDone()) )
{
  // Do whatever you want parallel to the evaluation of the Future objects

  // example
  System.err.println( "Not all are done yet." );
}
// process your results

// example:
String[] results = list.stream().map( Main::evalGet ).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Note: `priavte static <T> TevalGet(Future<T> fu)` is just a wrapper function to keep the lambda expression clean of exception-handling and looks similar to this:

```
private static <T> T evalGet( Future<T> fu )
  {
    T obj = null;
    try
    {
      obj = fu.get();
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException | ExecutionException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
  }
```

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440604/whether-to-use-invokeall-or-submit-java-executor-service