# ExecutorService.submit() vs ExecutorSerivce.invokeXyz()

Tags: java, multithreading

`ExecutorService` contains following methods:

- `invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)`
- `invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)`
- `submit(Callable<T> task)`

I am confused about the use of terms `submit` vs `invoke`. Does it mean that `invokeXyz()` methods invoke those tasks immediately as soon as possible by underlying thread pool and `submit()` does some kind of scheduling of tasks submitted.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798567/6357916) answer says "if we want to wait for completion of all tasks, which have been submitted to ExecutorService". What does "wait for" here refers to?

Answer (score 3):

Both `invoke..()` and `submit()` will execute their tasks immediately (assuming threads are available to run the tasks). The difference is that `invoke...()` will *wait for* the tasks running in separate threads to finish before returning a result, whereas `submit()` will return immediately, meaning the task it executed is still running in another thread.

In other words, the `Future` objects returned from `invokeAll()` are guaranteed to be in a state where `Future.isDone() == true`. The `Future` object returned from `submit()` can be in a state where `Future.isDone() == false`.

We can easily demonstrate the timing difference.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    Callable<String> c1 = () -> { System.out.println("Hello "); return "Hello "; };
    Callable<String> c2 = () -> { System.out.println("World!"); return "World!"; };
    List<Callable<String>> callables = List.of(c1, c2);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    System.out.println("Begin invokeAll...");
    List<Future<String>> allFutures = executor.invokeAll(callables);
    System.out.println("End invokeAll.\n");

    System.out.println("Begin submit...");
    List<Future<String>> submittedFutures = callables.stream().map(executor::submit).collect(toList());
    System.out.println("End submit.");
}
```

And the result is that the `callables` print their Hello World message *before* the `invokeAll()` method completes; but the `callables` print Hello World *after* the `submit()` method completes.

```
/*
Begin invokeAll...
Hello
World!
End invokeAll.

Begin submit...
End submit.
Hello
World!
*/
```

You can play around with this code in an IDE by adding some `sleep()` time in `c1` or `c2` and watching as the terminal prints out. This should convince you that `invoke...()` does indeed *wait for* something to happen, but `submit()` does not.