# Does a child thread in Java prevent the parent threads to terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I create and start a thread inside another thread, will it be a child thread? Does it prevent the termination of the parent thread while the child thread is running? For example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do Sth
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do Sth
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do Sth
                    }
                }).start();
                //Do Sth
            }
        }).start();
        //Do Sth
    }
    //Do Sth            
}).start();
```

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. Look up what setDemon does in Java.

Comment: Look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939076/wait-until-child-threads-completed-java

Comment: I had searched about the topic! I asked it because I think that it will be also useful to others and on the other hand I get where I'm wrong in my mentality about the threads! @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your code, there is a parent-child relationship between *objects*. However, there is no notion of a parent-child relationship between *threads*. Once the two threads are running they're basically peers.

Let's say that thread A starts thread B. Unless there's explicit synchronisation between them, either thread can terminate whenever it pleases without affecting the other thread.

Note that either thread can keep the *process* alive for as long as the thread lives. See [What is Daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java)

Comment: In my mind the threads creation are nested. There's a parent/child relationship between them although they doesn't make much sense they do share the same context class loader. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader%28%29

Comment: There is a concept of child threads in the context of ThreadLocal: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html

Answer (score 7):

> When I create and start a thread inside another thread, will it be a child thread?

Java has no real concept of "child" threads.  When you start a thread it inherits the daemon and priority from the "parent" but that's the end of the parent/child relationship.

```
// in Thread.init()
this.daemon = parent.isDaemon();
this.priority = parent.getPriority();
```

When the thread starts it runs along side its "parent" and there is no linkage between the two.

> Does it prevent the termination of the parent thread while the child thread is running?

No it does not.  However I suspect that you are really wondering if a thread can prevent the termination of the *application*.  If the child thread is non-daemon then even if the main thread (which is also non-daemon) finishes, your application will wait for the child thread to finish.  By definition, the JVM will wait for all non-daemon threads to finish.  Once the last non-daemon thread finishes, the JVM can terminate.

See: [What is Daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It will become a child thread, but it won't prevent parent thread from termination.

Answer (score 0):

There is no parent-child relationship in two threads. After Completion of `ParentThread`, `ParentThread` does not waiting for a
`ChildThread`.

```
public class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ParentThread pt=new ParentThread();
         pt.start();
         for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
             System.out.println("ParentThread alive: "+pt.isAlive());
             try{
                 Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
             }catch(Exception ex){
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
         }          
     }
 }

class ParentThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        ChildThread ct=new ChildThread();
        ct.start();
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            try{
                System.out.println("ChildThread alive: "+ ct.isAlive() + ", i = "+i);
                sleep(500);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    } 
}
class ChildThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            try{
                System.out.println("ChildThread i = "+i);
                sleep(500);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output (like):

```
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread alive: true, i = 1
ChildThread i = 1
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread i = 2
ChildThread alive: true, i = 2
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread i = 3
ChildThread alive: true, i = 3
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread i = 4
ChildThread alive: true, i = 4
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread i = 5
ChildThread alive: true, i = 5
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread i = 6
ChildThread alive: true, i = 6
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread alive: true, i = 7
ChildThread i = 7
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread i = 8
ChildThread alive: true, i = 8
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread alive: true, i = 9
ChildThread i = 9
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread alive: true, i = 10
ChildThread i = 10
ParentThread alive: true
ChildThread i = 11
ParentThread alive: false
ChildThread i = 12
ChildThread i = 13
ParentThread alive: false
ParentThread alive: false
ChildThread i = 14
ParentThread alive: false
ChildThread i = 15
ParentThread alive: false
ChildThread i = 16
ParentThread alive: false
ChildThread i = 17
ChildThread i = 18
ParentThread alive: false
ParentThread alive: false
ChildThread i = 19
ParentThread alive: false
ChildThread i = 20
```