# Is this multi-threading code guaranteed to always return zero?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am taking a book to do some mock test, I have found this question:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class AtomicVariableTest {

    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    static class Decrementer extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            counter.decrementAndGet(); // #1
        }
    }

    static class Incrementer extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            counter.incrementAndGet(); // #2
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new Incrementer().start();
            new Decrementer().start();
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

The answer:

> This program will always print 0.

But I think there is no guarantee that the threads will have completed when it prints the counter value.

I mean, most of the time it will return 0, but if you are strict with the theory there is no guarantee of this.

Am I correct?

Comment: Sure, I could try thousands of times without lucky ! I just want to know if you are agree

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  you are not actually asking a question with a specific answer, you are asking for **discussion**. This is **NOT** a forum and discussions is extremely **off-topic**.

Comment: This question is not asking for discussion, it's asking a specific question about how a specific code-snippet works.

Comment: I could change the question to "what is the correct answer?" ritght ... in fact, I think that question has only one answer

Comment: this is a duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939076/wait-until-child-threads-completed-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is guaranteed. And there is not guaranteed. There is no middle ground.

*In this case there is **no** guarantee that the result is always zero.* This is because the threads are not joined - and might never even have actually ran before the print!

For example, among other permutations, the sequence this code *could* have executed is:

```
counter.decrementAndGet();    // #1
System.out.println(counter);  // Main thread
counter.incrementAndGet();    // #2
// (and so on, at some arbitrary point after the print)
```

Avoiding such undesired interleaving/execution is handled in Java (as per the JLS) under happens-before relationships.

*If* the threads *were* joined (to the thread with the print) then a happens-before would have been established - in this case that would mean that the threads started and finished running - and the result would be guarantee to be zero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        final new Incrementer i = new Incrementer();
        threads.add(i);
        i.start();
        final new Decrementer d = new Decrementer();
        threads.add(d);
        d.start();
    }
    for (final Thread t : threads) { t.join(); }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

See one of the many duplicates: [Wait until child threads completed : Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939076/wait-until-child-threads-completed-java)

And this is why you use the `ExecutorService` or `ExecutorCompletionService` and never deal with thread management manually because it is extremely error prone otherwise.

Comment: even though it is correct now it is worded extremely unclear you need to put a code example to clarify where the `.join()` would be to make it as described.

Comment: I fixed it, you can all delete your comments you made while I was looking it up, it did not look right to me either.