# BitmapFactory returns null though there exist an image

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

Here I want to convert an image from String URL. Though there is an URL containing image, it returns null. I have shared code below.

```
private byte[] convertImageToByteArray(String imgPath)
{

    byte[] byteArray = null;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
    if(bmp != null)
    {

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            try 
            {
                stream.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            Bitmap bmpDefault = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.na);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //bmpDefault.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            bmpDefault.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
return byteArray;

}
```

Instead of executing if block, the control flow enters into else block and BitmapFactory.decodeFile() always returns null. Where I  went wrong?

Comment: what does `imgPath` refers to? is it valid image file? did you try to see its binary content?

Comment: imgPath is a valid URL

Comment: my URL is like www.facebook.com/abc/sampleImage.png

Comment: `decodeFile(String pathName)`

Added in API level 1
Decode a **file path** into a bitmap. If the specified file name is null, or cannot be decoded into a bitmap, the function returns null.

Comment: I have cross checked it. URL contails value. its not null.

Comment: do you know what does **file path** mean? read again `decodeFile` documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this reference, it might be [helpfull](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/converting-image-url-to-bitmap/) to you.

Note :- This function makes Network Connection, you should call it inside thread or AsyncTask. Otherwise it might throw `NetworkOnMainThread` Exception.

As the function is returning Bitmap, you will have to wait till your thread is executed so check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9939162/2930834).
which uses join()

I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad, I could help

Answer (score 3):

**Ravindra's** answer is helpful, for better utilization of image try Picasso lib,is mind blowing. It has also resize/crop method.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load("your url").into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        //do what ever you want with your bitmap 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these lines of code for it:-

```
    Bitmap bmImg;
   AsyncTask<String, String, String> _Task = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>()
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        String _imgURL  = "**HERE IS YOUR URL OF THE IMAGE**";

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {


            HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(_imgURL));
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
            System.out.println("main url"+mainUrl);
            httpRequest.abort();


        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        try
        {
            /////HERE USE YOURS BITMAP
         **bmImg** is your bitmap , you can use it any where i your class
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
_Task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```