# How to wait application until countDownTimer finish

Tags: android, countdown

Similar query: [wait until all threads finish their work in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java)

Hello,
I'm developing android application that contains some kind of count down timer. My problem is, that I have multiple count down timers, that sets text of TextView and have to work separately (first count down timer has to wait until the second one is finished etc.)

See code:

**MyCountDownTimer.java**

```
public class MyCountdownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
TextView tv;

    // default constructor
    public MyCountdownTimer (long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    // constructor
    public MyCountdownTimer(int hours, int mins, int secs,
    long countDownInterval, TextView tv) {
        super(3600000 * hours + 60000 * mins + secs * 1000, countDownInterval);
        this.tv = tv;
            // all other settings
    }   

    // when finished, set text of textview to done
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tv.setText("done!");
    }

    // when working periodically update text of text view to value of time left
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
tv.setText(/*function setting text of TextView based on time left*/);
    }
}
```

**Timer.java**

```
public class Timer extends Fragment {
Button bStart;
Button bStop;
TextView tvShowTime;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer, container, false);
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    bStart = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.bTimerStart);
    bStop = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.bTimerStop);
    tvShowTime = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.showTime);
    // setting on button start click
    bStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timerStart();
        }
    });

    // setting on button stop click
    bStop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timerStop();
        }
    });
}
    private void timerStart() {
        bStart.setClickable(false);
        int repeat = 2;
        int hour, mins, secs;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * repeat; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                //  setting working count down timer values
                mins = 1;

            } else {
                // setting resting count down timer values  
                secs = 30;
                    }
            timerCount = new MyCountdownTimer(hours, mins, secs, REFRESH_RATE,
            tvShowTime);
            timerCount.start();
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // HERE I WANT TO WAIT UNTIL COUNTDOWN IS DONE  //
            //   ATM SECOND, THIRD AND FOURTH COUNT DOWN    //
            //           TIMER IS STARTED                   //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

At the end I did 2 CountDownTimers where first one calls in onFinish() second one and second one calls the first one until repeat = 0; 
In final it was the best sotution for me. Anyway thanks for help, @Triode's answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Start your `SECOND, THIRD AND FOURTH COUNT DOWN TIMER` in `onFinish()` of Your `MyCountdownTimer`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put down the **timerStop()** method implementation and do not try to hide it,you need answer but you don't want others to benifit :s