# multithreading java xync

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to multithreading. I need to calculate integral by partial sums using multiple threads. I want to find out if all threads finished calculating to show general sum, I'm doing it using sleep(500) but it's stupid. How can i do it by the right way?

```
public class MainClass {
    private static int threadCount=10;
    public static double generalSum=0;
    private static ArrayList<CalculatingThread> threads;
    public static  void main(String[] args){
        Calculator.setA(0);
        Calculator.setB(2);
        Calculator.setN(500);
        threads=new ArrayList<CalculatingThread>();
        int div=500/threadCount;
        for (int i=0; i<div;i++){
            CalculatingThread thread=new CalculatingThread();
            thread.setJK(i*10,(i+1)*10-1);
            thread.start();
            threads.add(thread);
        }
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            System.out.println(generalSum);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class CalculatingThread extends Thread {
    private int j;
    private int k;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Partial sum: " + Calculator.calcIntegral(j, k));
        Calculator.addToSumm(Calculator.calcIntegral(j, k));
        //this.notify();
    }

    public void setJK(int j,int k) {
        this.j = j;
        this.k=k;
    }
}


public class Calculator {
    private  static double a;
    private  static double b;
    private  static int n;

    private static double InFunction(double x){
        return Math.sin(x);
    }
    private double sum=0;

    public static void setA(double a) {
        Calculator.a = a;
    }

    public static void setB(double b) {
        Calculator.b = b;
    }

    public static void setN(int n) {
        Calculator.n = n;
    }

    public static double calcIntegral(int j,int k)
    {
        double result, h;
        int i;

        h = (b-a)/n; //Шаг сетки
        result = 0;

        for(i=j; i <= k; i++)
        {
            result += InFunction(a + h * i - h/2); //Вычисляем в средней точке и добавляем в сумму
        }
        result *= h;
        return result;
    }

    public static synchronized void addToSumm(double sum){
        MainClass.generalSum+=sum;
    }
}
```

P.S. sorry, i know code is stupid, i will refactor it later

Comment: use join to sync the main thread with the threads you've created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
```

with

```
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
 }
```

This will make main thread to wait until all the created threads get completed. Also you can refer [wait until all threads finish their work in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java)

Comment: thanks man) i appreciate) i handled it by myself using wait and notify

Answer (score 0):

you can use [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) to make the main thread wait for the others:

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
>   another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> t.join(); causes the current thread to pause execution until t's
>   thread terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a
>   waiting period. However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS
>   for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as
>   long as you specify.

save every thread you create in an array and then do `join` on them

so your main should look like

```
public class MainClass {
    private static int threadCount=10;
    public static double generalSum=0;
    private static ArrayList<CalculatingThread> threads;
    public static  void main(String[] args){

        Calculator.setA(0);
        Calculator.setB(2);
        Calculator.setN(500);
        threads=new ArrayList<CalculatingThread>();
        int div=500/threadCount;
        for (int i=0; i<div;i++){
            CalculatingThread thread=new CalculatingThread();
            thread.setJK(i*10,(i+1)*10-1);
            thread.start();
            threads.add(thread);
        }
        try {
            for (Thread curr: threads) {
               curr.join();
            }

            System.out.println(generalSum);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

now on a side note, no series program is using `sleep` when it wants to wait. sleep is only used **when you actually need a delay in a background thread**

**P.S.**
do not refactor the code. it is excellent to post it like that, so i can see every mistake you do if u do. a lot better then most people posting only 1 line and then there is nothing i can do but ask for more details

Comment: thanks for good advice. i used notify and wait, but now i know two ways how to do it. What i meant saying that my code is bad - is that i used a lot of static variables - i think it's not right

Comment: @JenyaKirm might be, but unless there is something completely wrong in your program, i doubt anyone will say anything

Comment: @JenyaKirm btw, if you solved it in any other way you should write an answer for future programers