# Shared executor service among various worker

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to use a common thread pool among various reader objects. Each reader will read asynchronously using a thread from the pool. Here is how I define my executor :

```
public static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool();
```

I want to use it in TableReader objects. For example, there is a function readRows which will look like this :

```
executor.submit(new AsyncRowReader(...));
```

However, I am not sure how to handle the shutdown() step. The TableReader is part of a jar which can be used like this :

```
TableReader r = new TableReader(...);
while (not done) {
  r.readRow(...);
}
```

There could be multiple TableReader objects from a single application. I can shutdown the executor service once all of these are done. How can I detect that there no more tasks running? Is there a different type of thread pool I can use?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what shutdown does. You can `shutdown()` immediately after you have submitted your last worker and everything will still finish. You can `shutdownNow()` if you want to interrupt (via `Thread#interrupt()`) everything that's at this moment working and discarding everything that's still in queue.

Comment: @ToyElephant: Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java/36797569#36797569

Comment: @zapi : What if I don't know when my last request is filed? The application can open many reader objects. Reader objects don't have any relationship between them. I don't want the application to have to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html):

```
ExecutorCompletionService completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);

while (completionService.poll() != null) {
    System.out.println("Still working...");
}

executor.shutdown();
```