# How to define a rendevous in main thread for threads started in loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm quite new to multithreading and this is what I want to do:

How can I check if all my started threads have finished?

I start them by doing this

```
for (Auftrag auftrag: auftragsliste) {
  RunnableFS thread = new RunnableFS(auftrag, optionen, elmafs);
  thread.start();
}

// I want to do something here after all my above started threads have finished
```

I know that by `thread.join()` I could implement a point where the mainthread waits until the other one has finished. But if I do this in the for-loop I'm back to single threaded :(

Comment: What is `RunnableFS`?

Comment: @LutzHorn `RunnableFS` is my class that implements `Runnable`

Comment: @bish, why can't use ExecutorService? invokeAll() and iterating through all callable with Future.get() will achieve the purpose. Refer to this SE post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java/36797569#36797569

Comment: @Ravindrababu Thanks for the link and the documentation example in there. I'll have a look tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) from java.util.concurrent package are other alternatives to achieve similar use-cases.

Comment: After looking the different options of all the answers and comments in this questions I used a `CountDownLatch`. Works smooth. Thank you

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain a list of `RunnableFS`s, after starting all the threads, you can loop through them and do `join()` (btw i dont know what is `RunnableFS`)

```
List<RunnableFS> threads = new ArrayList<>();

for (Auftrag auftrag: auftragsliste) {
   RunnableFS thread = new RunnableFS(auftrag, optionen, elmafs);
   thread.start();
   threads.add(thread);
}

// Later
for(RunnableFS thread: threads){
   thread.join();
}
```