# Design pattern for checking asynchronous task dependencies before execution

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, design-patterns, language-agnostic

## The Problem

Given a number of asynchronously loaded dependencies, I want to trigger some code only after all dependencies are finished loading. As a simple example, consider the following pseudo-code:

```
bool firstLoaded = false, secondLoaded = false, thirdLoaded = false;

function loadResourceOne() {
    // Asynchronously, or in a new thread:
    HTTPDownload("one.txt");
    firstLoaded = true;
    if (secondLoaded && thirdLoaded) {
        allLoaded();
    }
}

function loadResourceTwo() {
    // Asynchronously, or in a new thread:
    HTTPDownload("two.txt");
    secondLoaded = true;
    if (firstLoaded && thirdLoaded) {
        allLoaded();
    }
}

function loadResourceThree() {
    // Asynchronously, or in a new thread:
    HTTPDownload("three.txt");
    thirdLoaded = true;
    if (firstLoaded && secondLoaded) {
        allLoaded();
    }
}

function allLoaded() {
    Log("Done!");
}

/* async */ loadResourceOne();
/* async */ loadResourceTwo();
/* async */ loadResourceThree();
```

## What I'm Looking For

This is a problem that I've found myself having to solve repeatedly in different languages and in different contexts. However every time I find myself using the tools provided by the language to hack together some simple solution, like returning each asynchronous resource as a Promise in JavaScript then using `Promise.all()` -- or loading each resource in its own thread in Python then using `threads.join()`

I'm trying to find a **design pattern** that solves this problem in the general case. The best solution should meet two criteria:

1. Can be applied to any language that supports asynchronous operations
2. Minimizes repetition of code (note that in my simple example the line `allLoaded();` was repeated three times, and the `if` statement preceding it was *practically* repeated, and wouldn't scale well if I need a fourth or fifth dependency)
3. Runs the final callback **as soon as possible** when all resources are loaded -- this one is hopefully obvious, but solutions like "check that all are loaded every 5 seconds" aren't acceptable

I tried flipping through the index of the Gang of Four's Design Patterns, but the few pattern names that jumped out at me as possible leads turned out to be unrelated.

Comment: If java is your programming language, have a look at various options @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java/36797569#36797569

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried flipping through the index of the Gang of Four's Design Patterns, but the few pattern names that jumped out at me as possible leads turned out to be unrelated.

This problem domain will require combining multiple design-patterns rather than a single design-pattern. Let's address the key requirements :

1. A task should be able to know when the tasks it depends on are complete
   so that it can start executing immediately.  This needs to be achieved without
   periodically polling the dependent tasks.
2. Addition of new dependencies to a task needs to be possible without the need to keep adding new `if-else` style checks.

For point 1, I would suggest that you take a look at the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The primary advantage of this pattern in your case would be that a task won't have to poll it's dependent tasks. Instead, each task that your task depends on will notify your task when it completes by calling the `update` method. The `update` method can be implemented intelligently to check against a pre-populated list of tasks that it depends on every-time the method is called. The moment all pre-configured list of tasks have called `update`, the task can launch it's worker (A thread for example).

For point 2, I would suggest that you take a look at the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). A `Task` has an `array` of dependent `Task` instances and an `array` of `Task` instances it depends on. If a task finishes execution, it calls `update` on each of the tasks in the array of tasks that depend on it. On the other hand, for a task to start executing, other tasks that it depends on will call it's `update` method.

If I had to define the above approach in pseudo code, it would look something as follows :

```
Task structure :
   array of dependents : [dependent Task instances that depend on this Task]
   array of dependencies : [Task instances this task depends on]

   function update(Task t) : 
       remove t from dependencies
       if(dependencies size == 0) 
          - start asynchronous activity (call executeAsynchronous)

    function executeAsynchronous() :
        - perform asynchronous work
        - on completion :
             - iterate through dependent array
               - call update on each Task in dependent array and pass it this Task

    function addDependent(Task t) :
       - add t to array of dependent tasks

    function addDependency(Task t) :
       - add t to array of dependencies
```

All said and done, don't go looking for a design pattern to solve your problem. Instead, come up with working code and work through it to improve its design.

---

**Note :** There is a small but significant difference between a framework and a design-pattern. If the objective is to build a task-dependencies framework using  design patterns, you are definitely going to need more than one design pattern. The above answer explains how to do this using the Gang of Four patterns. If the objective is to **not reinvent** the wheel, one can look at frameworks that already solve this problem.

One such framework is the *Spring Batch* framework that allows you to define  [sequential flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#SequentialFlow) and [split flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#split-flows) which can be wired together into a [job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/domain.html#domainJob) that defines the end to end processing flow.

Comment: The primary reason I was looking for a design pattern was that this feels like a problem which plenty of people have had before and has been solved time and time again. No reason to re-invent the wheel when there are so many advantages to be had by applying a standardized and well-understood solution.

Comment: I agree. Reinventing the wheel is a big no no. And for that reason, what you should be asking is whether there is a *framework* that already solves this problem rather than asking for a *design-pattern* to reinvent something that an existing *framework* already does. There is a small but significant difference between a *framework* and a *design-pattern*. That said, I did try to incorporate some well defined design patterns that can be combined to come up with your own solution/framework. Let me know if that helped/needs clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [Fork-Join pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model).

> In parallel computing, the fork–join model is a way of setting up and executing parallel programs, such that execution branches off in parallel at designated points in the program, to "join" (merge) at a subsequent point and resume sequential execution. Parallel sections may fork recursively until a certain task granularity is reached. Fork–join can be considered a parallel design pattern...

The implementation will be language dependent, but you can search for fork-join in combination with your language of choice. Note that you will not find asynchronous patterns in the Gang of Four. You would want a book specific to multithreading or parallel computing.

Comment: One quick question -- is there a common extension to the Fork-Join pattern to allow for multiple potential "subjoins"? For instance, in the image on the wiki page, suppose parallel task 2, sub-task A only requires sub-tasks A and B (but not sub-task C) from parallel task 1. Is there a way to say "when A and B complete, start A in task 2 - even if C isn't ready"? Essentially declaring the dependencies of future sub-tasks so that they kick off the instant they're able to

Comment: @stevendesu In your question, you specifically talk about two requirements namely the ability to notify tasks about the completion of it's dependencies and the ability to add more dependencies without the need to add new conditions. You also mentioned about not finding anything suitable in the Gang of Four patterns. In my humble opinion. none of these points seem to be addressed in the above answer. For the sake of other users, it would help that the question was edited to indicate that you were merely looking for the name of a pattern that represents submitting tasks and waiting for results..

Comment: @CKing While the solution wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it was the only answer I ever received that provided a design pattern for further research and exploration. Though not ideal, many programs can be re-architected to fit into the fork-join pattern. If you know of a better pattern, post an answer and I'll gladly switch the accepted one. The best I've got through my own research is "Future / Promise" which is less a design pattern and more a feature of some programming languages.

Comment: @stevendesu The fork-join pattern only talks about how programs can execute in parallel and join together to continue sequential execution. It does not talk about modelling/adding task dependencies and notifying dependencies. A solution that addresses the above concerns will use a combination of concurrency design patterns and OO design patterns. It **CAN'T** only use fork-join The key question is, do you want to build this yourself. If no, what you want is a framework that solves this already. If yes, you need more than one pattern. See my answer that is written from this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

How about a latch initialized with number of dependencies and the individual loader decrements it each time they finish.

This way as soon as the latch count = 0; we know all are loaded and can fire the callback / desired function.

For Java - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html