# Keeping main thread running with Thread.sleep vs CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading

I want my main thread to be running, as I have some listener that will be listening to request/messages in another thread and I don't want my main thread to die.

Which one is better

### CountDownLatch

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    startListener();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    latch.await();

}
```

### Or While with sleep

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    startListener();
    while (true){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: How will the main thread know when to resume/continue?

Comment: What does the listener do exactly? Between the two, countdown latch is better, but there might be constructs that fit even better.

Comment: @daniu : listener will be a JMS listener which will be listening the messages throughout the day, unless we stop the process.

Comment: @ernest_k , I don't want to process anything further in main thread. I want it to be alive, so that my listener thread will keep on listening to the messages.

Comment: @Sujeet I understand that It's about how the main thread will be notified that your listeners' job is done. Can you show the code of `startListeners()` or whatever code has to finish before the main thread dies?

Comment: `CountDownLatch.await` is a more sophisticated mechanism that would wait until you have counted down to 0, while `Thread.sleep` is rarely a good decision, particularly when it's repetitive. Both cases are bad, there is no way to stop either of them (the former requires `latch` to be passed in `startListener`, the latter needs a reference to the main thread to be able to interrupt it).

Comment: What about join those thread in main thread ? Refer to example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54022338

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your listener thread is [a non-daemon thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213348/1602555) you can let the main thread finish. The JVM will continue to run as long as there are non-daemon threads executing.

`CountDownLatch` would be a better solution if you plan to implement a graceful shutdown. You can hit the latch and let the main thread finish by executing a cleanup logic. Think how the application will shut down e.g. you get a `SIGTERM` singal when listener is reading a message from the queue, what then?

Comment: Thanks, Making it non-daemon works ! Is there any impact of making it non-deamon, do we need to take care of anything else ?

Comment: @Sujeet you can take a look at Spring's [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) to see what are the challenges of reading from JMS.

Comment: The only difference is that the JVM will keep running if this thread is alive.

Answer (score 2):

None.

First of all, if `startListener()` create a new thread, the application will keep running even if the main thread finishes. That's true as long as there is at least one non-daemon thread running. (This is different from C / C++ where the application is ending with the main. which you might confuse with).

Regarding the options you presented. Both will create an endless loop (without a way to exist), which is probably not the best practice. But if you must choose one of them the `latch` is better since it won't consume CPU every second.

Answer (score 0):

Both proposed methods would work, but I suggest to employ the main thread in synchronous processing of incoming messages. Messages then will be processed faster and with less resources (threads). See [A Simple Example of Synchronous Message Receives](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfb/index.html). Listener then is not needed.

Comment: Actually I have multiple different kind of listener and they are listening to different different topics in their own thread. So I think a single main thread listening might not be a good idea in this case