# Make other threads wait until ScheduledExecutorService completes all tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

The main goal is to run a method using ScheduledExecutorService and wait until all its tasks complete before resuming the main thread.

I've created a utility method in custom **Scheduler** class that accepts any Runnable:

```
public void scheduleFunction(Runnable function) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    final ScheduledFuture<?> producerHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(function, initialDelay, interval, MILLISECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(() -> { producerHandle.cancel(true); }, timeout, MILLISECONDS);
}
```

And use it like this in other class when I need execute its method in scheduled mode:

```
public void sendToKafka() {
  Scheduler.scheduleFunction(this::produce);
}
```

This work fine, except one thing.
When the main thread reaches **sendToKafka()** it calls Scheduler to schedule a function. Dut the main thread keeps running, at the same time the Scheduled function starts to work.

**Actual result**:
two threads running at the same time
[image]

**Expected result**:
when scheduler thread starts the main thread stops and waits until scheduler completes execution
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In this case, Use Join
https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-wait-for-threads

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating and abandoning a `ScheduledExecutorService` in this method, you should call `shutdown()` to support timely release of the resources. If you do that, you can call `awaitTermination` to wait for the completion of all pending jobs.

```java
public void scheduleFunction(Runnable function) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    final ScheduledFuture<?> producerHandle
        = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(function, initialDelay, interval, MILLISECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        producerHandle.cancel(true);
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }, timeout, MILLISECONDS);
    try {
        scheduler.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Note that when you don’t need interruption, you can simply use

```java
public void scheduleFunction(Runnable function) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(function, initialDelay, interval, MILLISECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(() -> scheduler.shutdown(), timeout, MILLISECONDS);
    try {
        scheduler.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

as shutting down the `ScheduledExecutorService` implies stopping to reschedule the job; only if there’s an ongoing execution it will be completed and `awaitTermination` will wait for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of solutions doesn't work. The scheduled tasks never runs in this examples. main thread is getting frozen as well.

Comment: Since the way the tasks are scheduled doesn’t differ from your original code, they should run exactly the same. [This runs smoothly](https://ideone.com/MODkKX)

Comment: Yeah, that works fine now, I used some synchronization - that's why it wasn't working. Thanks!