# Implementing callbacks in Java with Runnable

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'm used to write code in JavaScript-like or Erlang-like languages, where I can make callback functions in easy way. Now I have to write something in Java. I figured it out how to perform callback like this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Demo extends Thread{

    private int data;

    public void run(){
        ask_for_data(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                on_data();
            }
        });
    }

    public void on_data(){
        System.out.println("Async callback: " + data);
    }

    public void ask_for_data(final Runnable callback){
        System.out.println("2");
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                data = get_data();
                new Thread(callback).start();
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    public int get_data(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {};
        return 42;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo d = new Demo();
        d.start();
    }
}
```

Question is: is it correct approach?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

simply pass an interface (callback implementation) to your runnable like this

```
interface Callback {
    void callback(); // would be in any signature
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    Callback c; 

    public MyThread(Callback c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        // some work
        this.c.callback(); // callback
    }
}
```

and a simple tutorial about everything you need about thread  [here](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html)

Answer (score 7):

Your code is very complicated - you extend `Thread`, implement `Runnable` internally and within the `Runnable` create another `Thread`. That's not correct approach.

Interface `Runnable` can be considered as a command design pattern - it's a unit of work to be done and it has been designed to **separate** logic of "what have to be done" from the threading mechanisms.

I don't know if I get your problem correctly, but from what I understand, you just try to pass some parameters to the callback being run in separate thread. So why don't just introduce some class implementing `Runnable` (that's your unit of work to be done) and pass by constructor some work parameters. What I mean is something like below:

```
public class MyUnitOfWork implements Runnable {
  private final Data data;

  public MyUnitOfWork(final Data data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public void run() {
    // do something with data
  }
}
```

and later on:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Data(/* something */));
t.start();
```

Comment: You are right, but in my case `MyUnitOfWork` don't has to known what to do on callback - just run it. Sometimes it's very useful.